# Display qt output on Rasbian Lite

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, raspbian, qt6

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./qtGui
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

I am trying to run a program I cross-compiled for my rpi which shows an image, however I get some errors when trying to run it. I understand why I get the errors because I am using Rasbian Lite and I have no desktop environment. But how could i still run an application window from a program like QT (Like a main window or QML applications).

Main file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QImage myImage;
    myImage.load("/home/ulas/test.jpg");

    QLabel myLabel;
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));

    myLabel.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(qtGui LANGUAGES CXX)
message("CMAKE_SYSROOT " ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
message("CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE " ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link, ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE} -L${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wl,-rpath-link,${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE} -L${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}")

#include_directories(/home/julian/qt6rpi/include/)

add_executable(qtGui main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(qtGui Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui Qt6::Widgets)
```

Comment: Try to set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS before running your example to help debugging. But if you don't have an X server running on your target, then don't use xcb plugin. What about eglfs ?

Answer (score 1):

To run a Qt app without X11 on the pi you'll need a proper plugin. On recent Raspberry OS versions, you'll need eglfs (eglfs based on KMS in particular). So, if the plugin is available in your Qt build, then you can run your app with the `-platform eglfs` parameter:

```
./qtGui -platform eglfs
```

If it does not work, maybe the plugin is failing to load or it is not there at all and you need to build it. Use the variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to find out why eglfs is not loaded in that case.